# After upgrading Libreoffice to 5.3.1.2, previous working extensions results in error

Tags: libreoffice

The [read text](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/read-text) extension was working fine until I upgraded to Version: 5.3.1.2. After upgrading it shows error message

**"BASIC syntax error. Expected: )."**

Any work around or shall I downgrade? My OS is Ubuntu 16.10

**Edit:**
Just found that the bug is already reported, see [tdf#106529](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106529)

Comment: Please describe what actions and data are necessary to reproduce the problem.  Does it occur during installation of the extension?  It worked for me using Google Translate in 5.3.0.3 on Windows.

Comment: @JimK please ignore my question. Just found that it is a bug and is already been  reported,  see https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106529

Comment: Good to know.  I'll have to test my own code to see if it is compatible with the new requirement.