# Error in LibreOffice Base Access2Base Module Application

Tags: libreoffice

Today I've upgraded LibreOffice to 5.3.1.2 but now I have Macro's that produce an error.

I have done some programming in Base with Access2Base but now the database connection gives an error in Sub DBOpen as it does not recognize 'ThisDataBaseDocument' any more.

When I try to execute the Access2Base module 'Application' in the editor screen it gives the following error:

BASIC syntax error. Expected: )

and it stops in Function HtmlEncode, where indeed the ")" is missing in line:

```
sOutput = sOutput & Utils._UTF8Encode(Mid(pvString, l, 1).
```

Who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [After upgrading Libreoffice to 5.3.1.2, previous working extensions results in error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894816/after-upgrading-libreoffice-to-5-3-1-2-previous-working-extensions-results-in-e):

> The bug is already reported, see [tdf#106529](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106529).

So change to a different version of LibreOffice.

Eventually, people should update their macros to accomodate the new change.  You could use the contact form at http://www.access2base.com/access2base.html.